# What's up with PHP explode() patterns?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have the following string:

```
$str = "Hello, my name is Bob and I like 'pizza'. Do you like pizza??"
```

Currently I am able to split/explode this string on the whitespace using:

```
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
```

but I want to use the regex pattern `\W` like so:

```
$arr = explode('\W', $str);
```

This *should* separate all words that aren't punctuation, allowing the `'pizza'` part to be separated as `pizza`. Except it returns nothing (I get an empty array back).

What can I do?

Comment: Where does it say that `explode` takes Regexen? :P

Comment: i think your question is to extract a single quoted substring from the whole string. am i right?

Comment: @deceze - it doesn't, I kind of assumed it would. *Most* other languages, the split/whatever function takes a regex! :P

Comment: @deceze Regexenesens - FTFY

Comment: To save you from googling it to confirm like me: 'regexen' is a seldom used plural form of regex, used for humor. Party-poopers like me use 'regexes'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use preg_split:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 3):

`explode` does not do Regexen.
[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) does.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of explode